# Is including ng-binding in your css selectors a bad practice?

Tags: css, angularjs

I just ran across this piece of code in our code base

```
li.ng-binding span {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

and this selector doesnt apply to one of the li elements it was meant to apply to because of the `.ng-binding` present in the selector. Though this code works, isnt including `ng-binding` in a CSS selector a bad practice?

Comment: You are correct, because (amongst other things wrong with this approach) `ng-binding` is meaningless to either the document or the stylesheet (or anyone viewing/managing either). It simply indicates `ng-binding` class has been set for a given element, which has no inherent value to either context and is likely meant to inform some other layer of the web client (such as a script). It would not only be appropriate to avoid using such arbitrary selectors in your CSS, but also to avoid them in your document/HTML, if at all possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I agree with your hesitation.** CSS is designed primarily to enable the separation of document content from the document presentation ([separation of structure](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G140.html)), Since Angular is essentially a middleman [for binding to the attributes of HTML DOM elements](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_htmldom.asp), standard directives (like ngStyle) or custom directives [should be used to help style DOM elements](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#directives)

**In addition**;  after some initial investigation there is a class="ng-binding" which is used internally by Angular. Examining the ngBind source there are a few lines that adds the class and associates the binding with `.data:`

In Angular < 1.3 there is a reference to this:

```
 element.addClass('ng-binding').data('$binding', attr.ngBindHtml);
```

**I would not use this class.**

Comment: I agree as well, but it should be pointed out that this sort of violation occurs *extensively* throughout most javascript platforms, including many of the popular libraries, such as bootstrap. It may not be as apparent, but requiring that a given element have a class like `bootstrap-sort-button` and then using that class in the CSS as a selector encourages the exact same bad behavior the OP is asking about. Note that this isn't me saying that this behavior is excusable or that your answer overlooks this behavior, but rather me saying that when it comes to this issue,  "we need a bigger boat".

Comment: Thanks @Fergus, that answers my question!